# How to transpose an array in Python with no imports?

Tags: python, arrays, image-processing

I am doing an image processing exercise. The tasks are quite simple. First, I retrieve an array from a .ppm file that contains 75 rows and 300 values per row. The values correspond to a pixel color in RGB (0-255). Then, I have to display an image. Up to here all good, but the next task consists of changing the image into its grayscale version. So I use the [LUMA formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grayscale) to convert each set of three values in a row into a single value corresponding to the grayscale. Then, I make the program store that value in a new .ppm document (part of the task). However, because Python reads one column at a time, it stores the values in a column as a row. Essentially, it transposes the data so I end up with 100 rows of 75 values, instead of 75 rows of 100 values. How can I transpose this array so that it stores the information correctly into the .ppm document?

This is what I did. `s[0]` is the "width" of the array and `s[1]` the "height".

```
with open("greyscalepizza.ppm", "w+") as g:
    g.write("P2 \n100 75 \n255")
    for i in range(s[0]):
        for j in range(s[1]):
            if j%int(s[1])==0:
                g.write("\n")
            pixels[j][3*i]=round(0.299*pixels[j][3*i])
            pixels[j][(3*i)+1]=round(0.587*pixels[j][(3*i)+1])
            pixels[j][(3*i)+2]=round(0.114*pixels[j][(3*i)+2])
            gray = pixels[j][3*i]+pixels[j][(3*i)+1]+pixels[j][(3*i)+2]
            g.write("{:.0f} ".format(gray))
```

Comment: swap your for loops?

Answer (score 0):

To Transpose a 2 by 2 Matrix with No imports I have Created a FUnction which you can see in the following Sample code. I do not know if this will work for an Array.

```
def transposeMatrix(m):
    return map(list,zip(*m))

def getMatrixMinor(m,i,j):
    return [row[:j] + row[j+1:] for row in (m[:i]+m[i+1:])]

def getMatrixDeternminant(m):
    #base case for 2x2 matrix
    if len(m) == 2:
        return m[0][0]*m[1][1]-m[0][1]*m[1][0]

    determinant = 0
    for c in range(len(m)):
        determinant += ((-1)**c)*m[0][c]*getMatrixDeternminant(getMatrixMinor(m,0,c))
    return determinant

def getMatrixInverse(m):
    determinant = getMatrixDeternminant(m)
    #special case for 2x2 matrix:
    if len(m) == 2:
        return [[m[1][1]/determinant, -1*m[0][1]/determinant],
                [-1*m[1][0]/determinant, m[0][0]/determinant]]

    #find matrix of cofactors
    cofactors = []
    for r in range(len(m)):
        cofactorRow = []
        for c in range(len(m)):
            minor = getMatrixMinor(m,r,c)
            cofactorRow.append(((-1)**(r+c)) * getMatrixDeternminant(minor))
        cofactors.append(cofactorRow)
    cofactors = transposeMatrix(cofactors)
    for r in range(len(cofactors)):
        for c in range(len(cofactors)):
            cofactors[r][c] = cofactors[r][c]/determinant
    return cofactors

invM=getMatrixInverse(twoD)

import sys
for i in invM:
    for j in i:
        print(j,end=" ")
```

Answer (score 0):

To Transpose an array *pixel* with size *s[0]xs[1]*, you can do it in the following way.

```
for i in range(s[0]):
    for j in range(i+1, s[1]):
        temp=pixel[i][j]
        pixel[i][j]=pixel[j][i]
        pixel[j][i]=temp
```

This will transpose the array in **O(s[0]*s[1])**.